why my React native app for android is missing advertising packets while scanning using react-native-ble-plx library?
I am using react-native-ble-plx library https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ inside my React Native project(android). My app is missing advertising packets while scanning. Beacons advertising interval is 1s, but my app is detecting advertising signal from beacons with delay most often 10s, sometimes it goes 45s to 1min and missing beacon's signal.
here's my piece of code :
const SCAN_INTERVAL = 50;
const SCAN_WINDOW = 50;

const scanningOptions = {
scanInterval: SCAN_INTERVAL,
scanWindow: SCAN_WINDOW,
};
const scanAndConnect = () => {
manager.startDeviceScan(["0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"], scanningOptions, (error, device) => {

  if (error) {

   console.log(error) 
    }
    return
  }

console.log(device?.id,
  //////////////////////////////...TIME AND DATE...//////////////////////////

  let d = new Date()
  var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * '+5.5'));

  //////////////////////////////...LOG OF DETECTED DEVICES...//////////////////////////////

  let deviceResult = {
    deviceid: device?.id,
    devicename: device?.name,
    rssi: device?.rssi,
    date: nd.toLocaleString().slice(0, 9),
    time: nd.toLocaleString().slice(11, 18),
  };
  console.log(deviceResult, "deviceResult");
})

}
scanAndConnect()

Try using an off the shelf Android Beacon scanner app like BeaconScope that will give you a "packets per second" (PPS) measurement for the beacon after tapping on the detection row.  What PPS rate do you see?
